# How to integrate CGit with Gerrit as a replacement for Gitweb?

Tags: git, gerrit, cgit

I am trying to get [cgit](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/) v0.11.0 to work with Gerrit v2.11 as the in-built repository browser.

Based on Gerrit's [documentation](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/config-gerrit.html#gitweb), I was able to get Gitweb working by just specifying the following two settings in gerrit.config:

```
[gitweb]
        type = gitweb
        cgi = /path/to/gitweb/gitweb.cgi
```

However, the instructions for cgit are a little vague in the documentation. I tried changing the settings to following:

```
[gitweb]
        type = cgit
        cgi = /path/to/cgit/cgit.cgi
```

With these changes Gerrit showed the '(cgit)' link in the UI properly, but when I click on the link, I get a 'Not Found' error. The URL generated seems to be wrong (the name of the repo is concatenated to the URL without any separator):

```
https://gerrit.myserver.org:8443/gitwebAll-Projects.git/summary
```

With 'gitweb' as the provider, the URLs are generated diffently:

```
https://gerrit.myserver.org:8443/gitweb?p=All-Projects.git;a=summary
```

I tried running the same URL with 'cgit' as the provider and now I do not get the 'Not Found' error. Instead an empty page generated by cgit shows up, which says:

```
No repository selected
generated by cgit v0.11.0 at 2015-04-22 03:04:49 (UTC)
```

Has anyone successfully integrated cgit with Gerrit using the in-built gitweb.type = cgit? If so, can you share any specific gerrit/cgit configuration that I am missing?

Comment: Still a problem on 2016-11-04.  I *think* the cgit type assumes you will be using an external cgit.

Comment: Can You use local cgit? I have cgit localy, pointed to it from gerrit but I am getting "Not found" error on web...

Answer (score 1):

if your cgit is running from another web server or link, you only need to add the correct url for it.

```
[gitweb]
        type = cgit
        url = https://gerritServer/cgit/
```

https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com/Documentation/config-gitweb.html

Comment: and if this is local cgit?